# Can we Call EJB (Enterprise java bean) hosted on weblogic server from any other client (jboss client)?

Tags: jboss, client, ejb, weblogic

We have a EJB hosted in a WebLogic server. I have a client with wlfullclient.jar who is ready to call the same EJB. But the problem here is the dependency (wlfullclient.jar) is not scalable because of the way we are generating this jar. So, my team suggested me to try other alternates to call the same ejbs.

So, here my question is 'Is it possible to call ejbs hosted in WebLogic server from any other client? like JBoss client, etc'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLS documentation has a document: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT379

also, WLS installation has sample code about remote EJB clients.

The client stubs will depend of your EJB remote interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for the solution @devwebcl. It is working. 
but my question is 'can we call EJBs hosted in weblogic server from any other clients? i mean clients like jboss,etc other than weblogic client.

Comment: I understand you are using wlfulclient and is huge, so wls has wlthint3client.jar that can do the job for you. The issue here that you need (at least) WLS classes for the connection, such us, weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory, for the remote JNDI connection, therefore you still need some WLS proprietary classes

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. Thank you.